# How to not let bottom nav cover content

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, navbar

Im building a react app and am trying to make a bottom NavBar for mobile screens. The problem is that when setting the nav to position:fixed, bottom:0, and height:70px , it hides that 70px of content behind the nav.

I dont really like the idea of hiding the nav on scroll and the only thing I can think of right now is somehow limiting the size of the content so it doesnt go behind the nav. Im hoping someone can give me a more simple solution haha.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your goal, you can use CSS to add padding to the bottom of the content area.

For the fixed bottom Navigation bar, create a CSS class:

```
.nav-botton{
position: fixed
bottom:0
left:0
width: 100%
height:70px
background-color: #000
}
```

Then apply a class of .content to the container:

```
.content{
padding-bottom: 70px
}
```

React sample code

```
import React from 'react';
const app = () => {
  return(
   <div className="app">
    <div className="content">
    {/*Your content goes here*/}
    <div>
   <div className="nav-botton">
    {/*The bottom Navigation bar goes here*/}
    <div>
   <div>
    
)
}

export default App;
```

This should work